# php how to check a string in a steamcommunity changelog page

Tags: php, curl

I want to check in this page :
http://steamcommunity.com/sharedfiles/filedetails/changelog/688987034

For that I checked the "view-source" fonction of my google chrome, and I saw this =>
view-source:http://steamcommunity.com/sharedfiles/filedetails/changelog/688987034

Mis à jour le : 18 juin à 22h31                                                   changeLogs[1466281918] = {"timestamp":1466281918,"change_description":"Build 2.0 - Supply Crates remap commit","language":0};

So I wish to be able to check and compare the timestamp, and if my current timestamp is less, do my action (send a notification for exemple)

So here it's my first code to check if the string is present in the page =>

```
<?php

$url = "http://steamcommunity.com/sharedfiles/filedetails/changelog/688987034"; // This one result by a timeout
//$url = "http://www.mycustompage.com"; // This one work

$ch = curl_init($url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_BINARYTRANSFER, true);
$content = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);

$currentdate = time();
$search = "1466281918";

if(strpos($content, $search) !== FALSE) {
echo "ok";
}
else {
echo "nok";
}

?>
```

But when I try with the final url, I have a timeout from curl, and finally a "nok" result ...
Of course when I tried with a custom page (using a copy paste of the source view), that's worked ...
So I don't know what I did wrong, or if it's a security on the steamcommunity host.

Comment: try to see if `$content' gets anything?

Comment: @wolx.......redondo: that works fine for me. Is it possible you are triggering off some protection?

Comment: echo $content don't give anything :x @MuhammadSumonMollaSelim

Comment: if that's work for you @NeilMasters perhaps I have some trouble with my curl version ?

# curl -V
curl 7.26.0 (x86_64-pc-linux-gnu) libcurl/7.26.0 OpenSSL/1.0.1e zlib/1.2.7 libidn/1.25 libssh2/1.4.2 librtmp/2.3
Protocols: dict file ftp ftps gopher http https imap imaps ldap pop3 pop3s rtmp rtsp scp sftp smtp smtps telnet tftp
Features: Debug GSS-Negotiate IDN IPv6 Largefile NTLM NTLM_WB SSL libz TLS-SRP